# Foreign key may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a (in my opinion) quite simple setup, but I can't figure out why I keep getting this error when I run `Update-Database`:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.Breweries_dbo.Pages_PageId' on table 'Breweries' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.

I am trying to setup this structure:

`Brewery` > `Page` > `IdentityUser`

This is my classes:

```
public class Brewery
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid BreweryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Page")]
    public Guid PageId { get; set; }

    public virtual Page Page { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid PageId { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Content { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("CreatorUser")]
    public string CreatorUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual IdentityUser CreatorUser { get; set; }
}
```

I have seen a lot of other Stack Overflow posts and it seems like I should be setting something up in the `OnModelCreating`, but I can't get it right. I would like to avoid having a `ICollection<Brewery> Breweries` property on the `Page`, since I want many different entities to reference to the `Page` entity and it is irrelevant for a `Page` who is referencing to it.

I am new to Entity Framework and Code First so I might have approached this wrong without knowing. I would appreciate any help to setup the relationships correct.

Answer (score 0):

As the association between `Page` and `Brewery` is required, EF defaults to cascaded delete. But if there are many entities referring to `Page` there will be multiple cascade paths and you have to override the default:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Brewery>()
            .HasRequired(b => b.Page)
            .WithMany() // <= no inverse collection in Page.
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.PageId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

You can only do this by fluent mapping. Also, this replaces the attributes on `Brewery.PageId`.

Comment: I still get the same error. Any other suggestions? :/

Comment: You should look at other cascading foreign keys referring to `Page`, or other references from `Brewery`.